# Integrate hibernateTemplate with spring and Jsf

Tags: hibernate, spring, jsf

I have an error when I integrate JSF, Hibernate, and Spring. I have created some unit tests, and all of them work. I think that the problem is coming from JSF. I get this error:

```
failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
```

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with JSF. You're using [Spring's HibernateDaoSupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html), and you're not supplying it with either a Hibernate SessionFactory or a Spring HibernateTemplate. You must set one of those properties for a HibernateDaoSupport to work.

Take note that HibernateDaoSupport is considered legacy. If this is new development, you should be using the [currently recommended way of using Hibernate from Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate).